# Any way to group methods in Java/Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, pragma

I would like to be able to group similar methods and have them appear in my Outline view in Eclipse. This makes navigating large swaths of code a little easier on the eye, and easier to find methods you need. In Objective-C there was a pragma mark command that you could set.

Anything like that for java/eclipse?

Comment: You know that the Ctrl-O command allows for typing the first thing of what you need before typing enter?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I use the [Coffee Bytes plugin](http://code.google.com/p/coffee-bytes/) for code folding, specifically configuring it for folding code that has start and end tags.

Although the plugin is not downloadable off the [page listed on the Google Code](http://archive.realjenius.com/platform_support) page, it has been recompiled against Eclipse 3.5 and made available [elsewhere](http://incubator.apache.org/isis/com.cb.eclipse.folding.KAM-3.5.zip); the version appears to work against Eclipse 3.6 and 3.7 as well. It is also available in the [Yoxos marketplace](http://market.eclipsesource.com/yoxos/node/com.cb.eclipse.folding.feature.group).

I use the following notation to group getters and setters of properties along with declaration of the property, although the same notation could be extended for your use.

```
// {{ Id
private String id;

public String getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(final String id) {
    this.id = id;
}
// }}
```

Configuration of the same needs to be done by setting appropriate preference in the code folding section available via **Windows > Preferences > Java > Editor > Folding**. Remember to choose Coffee Bytes Java Folding, and enable support for User Defined Regions.

Although the support for grouping/folding is restricted to the editor, the natural order of the methods within the fold can be retain in the outline view. I'm afraid that I'm unaware of any grouping capabilities beyond this plug-in.

Comment: See http://kosiara87.blogspot.com/2011/12/how-to-install-coffee-bytes-plugin-in.html for a version that works in Eclipse 3.7 (Indigo)

Answer (score 5):

I really miss it from the days of Smalltalk.

The best way to denote these categories would be adding annotations to the code itself. You would then need to create a specialized outline view which uses these annotations. Sounds like a good Google Summer of Code project.

Comment: Yes me too. I think the code organisation was one of the things that made Smalltalk-80 so productive.

Answer (score 4):

To help with Vineet Reynolds answer, I would also like to offer this:

> USAGE:
>
> ```
> in User Defined Regions tab use e.g.:
>
> Start identifier: region    
> End identifier: endregion
> ```
>
> In code:
>
> ```
> //region SomeName
> your code
> //endregion SomeName
> ```
>
> Installation instructions:
>
> 1. Install plugin
> 2. Unpack the downloaded file eclipse-folding-plugin.tar.gz
> 3. Copy the contents of the:
> 4. features folder => eclipse features folder
> 5. plugins folder => eclipse plugins folder
> 6. Configure plugin in Eclipse:
> 7. Select "Windows->Preferences"
> 8. Select "Java->Editor->Folding"
> 9. Check the "Enable folding" option
> 10. Select "Coffee Bytes Java Folding" in the "Select folding to use:" option
> 11. Check "User Defined Regions" in the "General Fold Setting:" option

This is from: http://kosiara87.blogspot.com/2011/12/how-to-install-coffee-bytes-plugin-in.html

Answer (score 2):

As to your original question, I believe that is not possible with Java/Eclipse.

However, if you have a group of similar methods that you need to distinguish from another group of methods within the same class, why not **create a new class** with the group of similar methods?

Comment: i mean for methods inside of a class. sometimes a class can have a lot of methods.

Comment: That sounds like the "Extract class" refactoring. http://www.refactoring.com/catalog/extractClass.html is the best hit I could find quickly but google "extract class" and I'm sure you'll find more.

Comment: In many cases it does not mean it should be refacotored out. For example, getters/setters are a category, event handling, actions, and more.

Answer (score 1):

If you mean group by name, click the button '**Sort**' on 'Outline view'.

Moreover, there are some **filters** in the view to 'hide static', 'hide non-public'...

Answer (score 1):

I just ran across this and thought I should point out that while this doesn't exactly meet your original statement you can add a `@category` directive in the documentation block of each method then filter for just the method categories you would like to see.  I have used this to only look at those groups of methods I am interested in at any one time.