# Coffee-bytes code folding plugin for eclipse not working

Tags: eclipse, plugins, folding

I have followed the advice here:

[getting an overview perspective of all methods in a class in Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8382018/getting-an-overview-perspective-of-all-methods-in-a-class-in-eclipse/8382333#8382333)

and here:  http://itekblog.com/code-folding-in-eclipse-tutorial/#comment-150

But it never seems to register the plugin, (yes, I restart eclipse) -- it just gives the same preferences options that existed prior to installing the plugin.

I'm using Eclipse Indigo service release 2, on windows 7.

The second link seems to reference the most recent version of the coffee-bytes plugin, and I have double and triple checked the I'm putting the correct files in the correct directory.  I have also tried using the "dropins" folder instead of the "plugins" folder.  Nothing seems to work.

I am wondering if it could be an environment variable, file permissions?  Some other configuration within eclipse which enables plugins generally?

Comment: well, looks like I found my own answer...  in the comments here:  http://kosiara87.blogspot.com/2011/12/how-to-install-coffee-bytes-plugin-in.html

Apparently my guess of a permissions related problem was correct.  Running eclipse just one time as administrator does the trick. (right click eclipse.exe or the shortcut or task but, then choose run as administrator)  You do it just once, check the preferences>java>editor>folding and it should now give you option to select coffee bytes.

After this you can run eclipse normally and it still loads the plugin.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

well, looks like I found my own answer... in the comments here:

http://kosiara87.blogspot.in/2011/12/how-to-install-coffee-bytes-plugin-in.html

Apparently my guess of a permissions related problem was correct. Running eclipse just one time as administrator does the trick. (right click eclipse.exe or the shortcut or task but, then choose run as administrator) You do it just once, check the `preferences>java>editor>folding` and it should now give you option to select coffee bytes. After this you can run eclipse normally and it still loads the plugin.

Comment: I created a fork and an update site for the old coffee bytes code folding plugin that works with Eclipse Neon: https://github.com/stefaneidelloth/EclipseFolding/raw/master/com.cb.platsupp.site